# Stretch node width without to stretch the parent width

Tags: jquery, xhtml

Is there anyway to stretch the width of a new row without to stretch the width of parent node (table)?

Structure example:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="div_1"> Block 1 </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="div_2"> Block 2 </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="div_3"> Block 3 </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="div_4"> Block 4 </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery code:

```
var newRow = "<tr><td colspan="2"><div>This is a great row, bla,bla,bla....</div></td></tr>";
$('#div_1').closest('tr').after(html);
```

I want to put the new row without to stretch the table's width.

Answer (score 1):

Give the table itself a fixed width and then it shouldn't expand to fit its contents.

Comment: It not works, I tried:

var sizeTest = $('#div_1').closest('table').outerWidth();
$('#div_1').closest('tr').after(html);
$('#div_1').closest('table').width(sizeTest);

I done it because my table is dinamic. But the my columns resized.

Comment: Do you not just know a fixed width for your table to be? Are you re-calling your resizing code after adding the new row, because it may be re-setting. I can't really tell without the code for it.